# Apache2 Xdebug not stopping in breakpoint in PhpStorm

Tags: apache2, phpstorm, xdebug, php-7.3

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have my projects on a plain Apache 2 with PHP 7.3. I have installed Xdebug but for some reasons I can't make it stop at the breakpoint.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing some configs here? I tried calling `xdebug_get_code_coverage();` function to check if I do have Xdebug installed and yes the function does exist.

I also have the PhpStorm configs set.

[image]

I have these entries on all my php.ini files. apache2, cli and fpm. just to make sure

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

My listener is also turned on and my breakpoints are set:

[image]

But when I hit `http://localhost/info/test.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1`
its not stopping on the breakpoints.

Comment: You are using Xdebug 3 but have Xdebug 2 config params. That will not work. Check these answers (they are pretty much the same). Ignore that those are for VSCode -- there is nothing in the answer about the IDE used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65350070/783119 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141934/783119

Comment: P.S. You should have read what Xdebug tells you on your screenshot -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhRvk.png . It says what to do right there, for MANY params.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks bro. finally made it working! my configs are quite different but knowing the issue is xdebug version really helps me!

Comment: In such case please post your final solution (what you had to change in config / anything else to change in the IDE settings) -- this will be helpful for other users in a similar situation (and having an answered and accepted question helps with visibility (you can accept your own answer after a small delay))

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315741/phpstorm-debugger-not-stopping-at-certain-breakpoints/19072911#19072911 ?