# Getting Xdebug 3 in PhpStorm working with MAMP Pro 6 and Mac M1

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm using PhpStorm with MAMP Pro 6 on a Mac M1 and I can't get Xdebug to run.
It don't stop on breakpoints outside the `index.php` in the project root.

This is the Xdebug part of php.ini

```
MAMP_Xdebug_MAMPzend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug,trace
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
```

I'm calling the page with https: ... :8890

The validation is only working on http :8888

If I try to use "https" I got this:

> Specified URL is not reachable, caused by: 'No subject alternative DNS name matching om-base-ob found'

Could that be hint? Or is the problem a missing mapping, which I don't understand!
Or the

I have no clue where to start, to solve the problem. Hope someone can bring me on the right track. I've attached all config screens. From my point of view this "zero-debug thing" should working with this settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 14 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 759
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="14" id="360180155"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 15 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2040
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="15" id="360180156"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 16 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/helpers/remotecontrol/remotecontrol_handle.php -n 2710
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="16" id="360180157"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 17 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/helpers/remotecontrol/remotecontrol_handle.php -n 2709
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="17" id="360180158"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 18 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2025
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="18" id="360180159"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 19 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/framework/yiilite.php -n 5831
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="19" id="360180160"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 20 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 742
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="20" id="360180161"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 21 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 744
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="21" id="360180162"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 22 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1371
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="22" id="360180163"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 23 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1878
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="23" id="360180164"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 24 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2028
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="24" id="360180165"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 25 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1377
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="25" id="360180166"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 26 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1887
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="26" id="360180167"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 27 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1376
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="27" id="360180168"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 28
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="28"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/index.php" lineno="12"></stack></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- run -i 29
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[eyJncm91cHMiOlt7ImdpZCI6IjY5MiIsInNpZCI6IjQyNDg3NyIsImdyb3VwX25hbWUiOiJNeSBmaXJzdCBxdWVzdGlvbiBncm91cCIsImdyb3VwX29yZGVyIjoiMSIsImRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjoiIiwibGFuZ3VhZ2UiOiJlbiIsInJhbmRvbWl6YXRpb25fZ3JvdXAiOiIiLCJncmVsZXZhbmNlIjoiMSIsInBhZ2VCcmVhayI6bnVsbCwibGluayI6IlwvaW5kZXgucGhwXC9hZG1pblwvcXVlc3Rpb25ncm91cHNcL3NhXC92aWV3XC9zdXJ2ZXlpZFwvNDI0ODc3XC9naWRcLzY5MiIsInF1ZXN0aW9ucyI6W3si
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="29" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[36018] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 30
[36018] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="30" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[36018] Log closed at 2022-01-28 08:00:49.299638

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 14 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 759
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="14" id="360210029"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 15 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2040
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="15" id="360210030"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 16 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/helpers/remotecontrol/remotecontrol_handle.php -n 2710
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="16" id="360210031"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 17 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/helpers/remotecontrol/remotecontrol_handle.php -n 2709
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="17" id="360210032"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 18 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2025
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="18" id="360210033"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 19 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/framework/yiilite.php -n 5831
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="19" id="360210034"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 20 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 742
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="20" id="360210035"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 21 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 744
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="21" id="360210036"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 22 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1371
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="22" id="360210037"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 23 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1878
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="23" id="360210038"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 24 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2028
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="24" id="360210039"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 25 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1377
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="25" id="360210040"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 26 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1887
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="26" id="360210041"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 27 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1376
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="27" id="360210042"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 28
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="28"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/index.php" lineno="12"></stack></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- run -i 29
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[eyJtZW51ZXMiOnsiMSI6eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJ0aXRsZSI6IlN1cnZleSBzZXR0aW5ncyIsIm5hbWUiOiJzZXR0aW5ncyIsIm9yZGVyaW5nIjoiMSIsImxldmVsIjoiMCIsImRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjoiU3VydmV5IHNldHRpbmdzIiwiZW50cmllcyI6eyI1NSI6eyJpZCI6IjU1IiwibWVudV9pZCI6IjEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjpudWxsLCJvcmRlcmluZyI6IjEiLCJuYW1lIjoib3ZlcnZpZXciLCJ0aXRsZSI6IlN1cnZleSBvdmVydmlldyIsIm1lbnVfdGl0bGUiOiJPdmVydmlldyIsIm1lbnVfZGVzY3JpcHRpb24i
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="29" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[36021] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 30
[36021] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="30" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[36021] Log closed at 2022-01-28 08:00:50.039697

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 14 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 759
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="14" id="360190057"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 15 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2040
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="15" id="360190058"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 16 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/helpers/remotecontrol/remotecontrol_handle.php -n 2710
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="16" id="360190059"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 17 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/helpers/remotecontrol/remotecontrol_handle.php -n 2709
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="17" id="360190060"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 18 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2025
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="18" id="360190061"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 19 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/framework/yiilite.php -n 5831
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="19" id="360190062"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 20 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 742
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="20" id="360190063"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 21 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 744
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="21" id="360190064"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 22 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1371
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="22" id="360190065"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 23 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1878
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="23" id="360190066"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 24 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 2028
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="24" id="360190067"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 25 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1377
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="25" id="360190068"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 26 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1887
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="26" id="360190069"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 27 -t line -f file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/application/controllers/admin/dataentry.php -n 1376
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="27" id="360190070"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 28
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="28"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///Users/myUser/Projects/myClient/www/test/index.php" lineno="12"></stack></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- run -i 29
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[eyJtZW51ZXMiOnsiMSI6eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJ0aXRsZSI6IlN1cnZleSBzZXR0aW5ncyIsIm5hbWUiOiJzZXR0aW5ncyIsIm9yZGVyaW5nIjoiMSIsImxldmVsIjoiMCIsImRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjoiU3VydmV5IHNldHRpbmdzIiwiZW50cmllcyI6eyI1NiI6eyJpZCI6IjU2IiwibWVudV9pZCI6IjEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjpudWxsLCJvcmRlcmluZyI6IjIiLCJuYW1lIjoiZ2VuZXJhbHNldHRpbmdzIiwidGl0bGUiOiJHZW5lcmFsIHN1cnZleSBzZXR0aW5ncyIsIm1lbnVfdGl0bGUiOiJHZW5lcmFsIHNldHRp
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="29" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[36019] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 30
[36019] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="30" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[36019] Log closed at 2022-01-28 08:00:50.778079
```

[image]

[image: Debug-Session]

[image: Website & validation]

[image: files]

Comment: What's the root of the project in IDE? Please share the absolute path.

Comment: just added a screenshot - do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, that would work, thanks. Could you please attach a screenshot of a debug window when it hits the first breakpoint. It stops at index.php if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I attached some screens

Comment: I solved the problem. I deleted all breakpoints and new it worked!! I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315741/phpstorm-debugger-not-stopping-at-certain-breakpoints), there suspend breakpoints came up - so I delete my breakpoints. Thanks Dmitrii for your support.

Comment: For me it was PHP/PhpStorm setup to use Docker PHP image, but Mac was running it's own PHP service and it did not reach PhpStorm. Had to stop Mac PHP service

Comment: after restart problem still there.
 '''where php
php: aliased to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php7.4.21.ini"
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php '''