# PhpStorm and Xdebug ignoring some of the file

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I'm having this weird issue where PhpStorm debugger would step into some files but not others, the project only has one route mapping and both files are on a very similar location, already reviewed things [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315741/phpstorm-debugger-not-stopping-at-certain-breakpoints) without any luck, my current config is as follows:

[image]

This is the output for my Xdebug when I run the PHP file that it won't reach.

```
[91] Log opened at 2023-10-13 11:04:12.557125
[91] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking for client discovery headers: 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR'.
[91] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[91] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[91] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 172.27.0.1:9009.
[91] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '172.27.0.1:9009', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[91] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not connect to client host discovered through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9009.
[91] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.27.0.1:9009 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), host.docker.internal:9009 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[91] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/bcs/assets/components/bcs/rest/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.24RC1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="91"><engine version="3.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[91] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 1 -- KHN0cmluZykoaW5pX2dldCgneGRlYnVnLmNvdmVyYWdlX2VuYWJsZScpLic7Jy5pbmlfZ2V0KCd4ZGVidWcucHJvZmlsZXJfZW5hYmxlJykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfYXV0b3N0YXJ0JykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfY29ubmVjdF9iYWNrJykuJzsnLmluaV9nZXQoJ3hkZWJ1Zy5yZW1vdGVfbW9kZScpKQ==
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="1"><property type="string" size="635" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[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]]></property></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n show_hidden -v 1
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_depth -v 1
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n max_children -v 100
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n extended_properties -v 1
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n notify_ok -v 1
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 7 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="7" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 8 -n breakpoint_include_return_value -v 1
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="8" feature="breakpoint_include_return_value" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 9 -c 1
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="9" success="1"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- status -i 10
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="10" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 11
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="11" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/bcs/assets/components/bcs/rest/index.php" lineno="11"></xdebug:message></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 12 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 13 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 14 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="14"><property type="string" size="13" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTkyLjE2OC4wLjEwNA==]]></property></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 15 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9QT1JUJ10p
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="15"><property type="string" size="2" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ODA=]]></property></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 16 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFUVVFU1RfVVJJJ10p
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="16"><property type="string" size="52" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2Jjcy9hc3NldHMvY29tcG9uZW50cy9iY3MvcmVzdC9pbmRleC5waHA/X3Jlc3Q9VXNlcg==]]></property></response>

[91] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 17
[91] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="17" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[91] Log closed at 2023-10-13 11:04:12.603421
```

Also I'm 100% sure the script is called because I can see the output on the browser from calling it, also triggering another script inside the core folder actually starts the debugger and let's me step debug without any problems what I'm missing?

Comment: The only thing I can make from the log is: 1) the IDE sets the breakpoint on line # 11 in that `/var/www/html/bcs/assets/components/bcs/rest/index.php` file. Can you please show what kind of line that is (what is there). A screenshot with how breakpoint looks should be good enough  to have an idea. Maybe it's some kind of "unhittable" line where the actual "break line" is on different line (although Xdebug has a special functionality for resolving such breakpoints for a few years now and PhpStorm enables such option during debug, unless you have disabled it ofc, which is not the case here).

Comment: 2) Accordingly to your screenshot you have configured the "PHP | Servers" entry to use 443 port (HTTPS). But the actual request is done using plain HTTP on port 80. Could be a mistake in URL on your end or some transparent traffic proxy (nginx for example). Duplicate that "PHP | Servers" entry and change port to `80` instead of `443`. This way you will cover both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: 3) So if I'm right (I believe so), the issue will be in #2. This means that you have one of the "ignore connection...." options enabled in PhpStorm's Xdebug settings (otherwise it would told you about connection from unregistered server/address. Show a screenshot of your PhpStorm Xdebug settings screen.

Comment: Great catch @LazyOne the issue was related to the http vs https setting, thanks a lot! if you want put it as answer to approve it I'll do it right away, and again thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot you have configured your "PHP | Servers" entry to use port `443` (which is HTTPS). At the same time, according to the Xdebug log the actual request is done using plain HTTP on port 80. This could be a mistake in the URL on your end or perhaps some transparent traffic proxy (nginx for example).

Duplicate that "PHP | Servers" entry and change port to `80` instead of `443`. This way you will cover both access scenarios: HTTP and HTTPS.

[image]

---

**P.S.** It looks like you have "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations" option enabled in PhpStorm settings (on "PHP | Debug" settings page). If you would have it enabled then the IDE would show you a warning/dialog about unknown server configuration…

The IDE uses the server name & port pair to decide what config to use. And since you did not had the required combo and that option was enabled… PhpStorm was silently dropping the debug session (as configured by the user).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configuration" setting!!!!